# How to add drawerIcon to a drawer navigator that contains a nested stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-stack

I have a stack navigator which is then nested inside a drawer navigator. I want to have an icon for each of the routes in the stack navigator to then show in the drawer menu.

I have tried to use the navigationOptions to provide each route with a drawer icon in the stack navigator but this did not work.

```
const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Setting: {
      screen: SettingScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Feather name="settings" style={{ fontSize: 24, color: tintColor }} />,
      },
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Feather name="home" style={{ fontSize: 24, color: tintColor }} />,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'screen' : 'float',
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: <MenuButton navigation={navigation} />,
    }),
  }
);

const MainNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: StackNavigation,
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
  }
);
```

No icons are applied when attempted this way. Possibly because stack navigator does not have a drawerIcon option? But then I how do I apply them to each route individually...

Answer (score 1):

If you have two paths,

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
...
const MainTab = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Setting: {
      screen: SettingScreen
    }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      drawerIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor, image }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          iconName = "home";
        } else if (routeName === "Setting") {
          iconName = "rocket";
        }
        return (
          <Icon
            name={iconName}
            size={horizontal ? 20 : 25}
          />
        );
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: 1) Again this only applies an icon for one route in the drawer menu. I would like both route options (setting and home) to display in the drawer nav with their own icons. 2) My routes are not explicitly defined in drawer navigator otherwise I would not have an issue. Instead the stack navigator is nested within my drawer nav.

Comment: As you can see by looking at my code again, I'm returning the icon to my respective path. If you do like my code, you can get icons on the home screen and on the setting screen.

Comment: If I don't nest the stacknavigator, there is a much cleaner solution as presented by Ponleu. However, I am looking for a solution which allows me to continue using my nested stacknav within my drawernav.

Comment: @PJately If you take advantage of Ponleu's answer, you have to create many files and produce code. That is unnecessary. The reason why you can't solve it with what you want is that you can't read the screen value of the stack from the current module.

Comment: 1) Your solution does not make use of the nested StackNavigation. 2) If I took the approach of not nesting the stackNavigator, then Ponleu's answer would require less code and is easier to read.
However, I have a nested stackNavigator within my drawerNav so your solution would not work for that.

Comment: @PJately If you added a code like my answer, you can delete the same screen in the stack navigator and add a drawer Navigator.